# Drupal 8, Twig - how to output fields from a custom view template, and check for taxonomy terms

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I want to output the values of a taxonomy field that's rendered from a view:

```
<h4>{{ label }}</h4><!-- Does show -->

<p>{{ content.field_event_type }}</p><!-- Doesn't show -->

<p>
  {{ content.field_date }}<!-- Doesn't show -->
  <br>{{ content.field_location }}<!-- Doesn't show -->
</p>

<a href="{{ url }}" aria-label="" class="btn btn-primary my-2 p-3">Read event details</a>
```

Also, field_event_type is a taxonomy field. I'd like to be able to check if it has a given taxonomy, as well as output the values as above. For example:

```
{% if content.field_event_type.has_term("webinar") %}
    <p>Is webinar</p>
{% endif %}
```

But I can't find anything to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{% set tid = node.yourTaxonomyField.target_id %}
{% if tid %}
  {{ drupal_field('field_desired_field', 'taxonomy_term', tid) }}
{% endif %}
```